# Stop vim from flashing command prompt in Windows?

Tags: windows, vim, command-line

Vim under win32 opens a command prompt (`vimrun.exe` actually, which opens in a terminal window) on every external command, `silent` or not. Yes, the terminal closes automatically, but it is still quite annoying.

This makes plugins that make extensive use of external commands, such as [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/) (it runs a command on buffer open/save), a real pain.

Is there some way to fix this behavior? What I want is for the terminal to open only for non-`silent` commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to bring closure: I wrote a replacement runner utility for Vim on Windows that doesn't open a visible command prompt. Here it is: [vimrun-silent](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/vimrun-silent).

Answer (score 3):

Rather than just `![windows command]` you might try:

```
!start /min [windows command]
```

Alternatively, if you define a shortcut to a windows app you can click on the shortcut's properties and set it up to run as 'Minimized' rather than as 'Normal'

In both cases above an app button will show up on taskbar as the app is opened, as there would be for any minimized application.  But it's less intrusive than having an actual window open.

*NOTE* The !start command solution runs the command asynchronously, resumes Vim immediately without waiting for the command to complete, which may often not be what you want.  In that case the use of shortcut set up to run as minimized is better solution.